# Plot R^2 Value over time in bubble chart using gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate R^2 of a trendline over time with the help of gganimate and ggpubr, in a bubble chart like so below:

```
ggraph1= ggplot(dataset, aes(x=bbcarshare, y=WirelessShare, size=carcount))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title='Date:{closest_state}')+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+
  stat_cor(aes(label=..rr.label..))+
  transition_states(Date)
```

however this returns an error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "group", value = "") :
replacement has 1 row, data has 0

It seems this method may be impossible, is there another method that could show R^2 over time along with the geom_smooth linear regression?

Comment: I suspect that if you first do it with base graphics, that a method to do it with ggplot facility will become apparent. It’s even possible there is already an example on SO. Have you looked.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to spin your own. Here I calculate r^2 for each observed value of depth, then display the first one in each case. (otherwise the text will get overwritten dozens or hundreds of times and will look bad and render slower.)

```
library(tidyverse)rr
library(gganimate)
diamonds |>
  mutate(rr = cor(carat, price)^2, .by = depth) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(rr, 3)), x = 3.5, y = 2000, size = 5,
            data = . %>% slice(1, .by = depth)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  transition_states(depth)
```

[image]

Comment: That example is especially interesting because it demonstrates that the linearity assumption is false and that later values for which it incorrect are another sufficient numerous to shift the slope to reflect either non-linearity or the heteroschedasticity.